# Error with GIT_ASKPASS_TOKEN when trying to clone git repository in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I try to checkout a repository from Android Studio 3.4.2 (Git 2.22). In the Clone Repository dialog I provided the correct URL and pressed the "Test" button. The result is an error "Illegal value of environment variable value GIT_ASKPASS_TOKEN"

Any ideas what is going wrong? I can clone the repository from the command line but not from within Android Studio.

Here's the excerpt from the log file:

```
2019-08-14 12:49:27,463 [ thread 15] INFO - #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - [.] git version
2019-08-14 12:49:28,026 [unnerw.exe] INFO - #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - git version 2.22.0.windows.1
2019-08-14 12:49:28,041 [ thread 15] INFO - ea.config.GitExecutableManager - Git version for C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe : 2.22.0
2019-08-14 12:49:28,119 [ thread 15] ERROR - #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - Illegal value of environment variable value GIT_ASKPASS_TOKEN:
com.intellij.execution.IllegalEnvVarException: Illegal value of environment variable value GIT_ASKPASS_TOKEN:
at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.createProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:390)
at com.intellij.execution.process.OSProcessHandler.startProcess(OSProcessHandler.java:51)
at com.intellij.execution.process.OSProcessHandler.<init>(OSProcessHandler.java:44)
at com.intellij.execution.process.KillableProcessHandler.<init>(KillableProcessHandler.java:49)
at com.intellij.execution.process.KillableProcessHandler.<init>(KillableProcessHandler.java:57)
at git4idea.commands.GitTextHandler$MyOSProcessHandler.<init>(GitTextHandler.java:176)
at git4idea.commands.GitLineHandler$1.<init>(GitLineHandler.java:147)
at git4idea.commands.GitLineHandler.createProcess(GitLineHandler.java:147)
at git4idea.commands.GitTextHandler.startProcess(GitTextHandler.java:73)
at git4idea.commands.GitHandler.start(GitHandler.java:491)
at git4idea.commands.GitHandler.runInCurrentThread(GitHandler.java:439)
at git4idea.commands.GitImplBase.doRun(GitImplBase.java:157)
at git4idea.commands.GitImplBase.run(GitImplBase.java:125)
at git4idea.commands.GitImplBase.run(GitImplBase.java:100)
at git4idea.commands.GitImplBase.runCommand(GitImplBase.java:50)
at git4idea.commands.GitImpl.runCommand(GitImpl.java:54)
at git4idea.commands.GitImpl.doLsRemote(GitImpl.java:734)
at git4idea.commands.GitImpl.lsRemote(GitImpl.java:595)
at git4idea.checkout.GitCloneDialog.test(GitCloneDialog.java:37)
at com.intellij.dvcs.ui.CloneDvcsDialog$7.run(CloneDvcsDialog.java:370)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:727)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:403)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2019-08-14 12:49:28,119 [ thread 15] ERROR - #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - Android Studio 3.4.2 Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245
2019-08-14 12:49:28,119 [ thread 15] ERROR - #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o
2019-08-14 12:49:28,119 [ thread 15] ERROR - #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - OS: Windows 10
2019-08-14 12:49:28,119 [ thread 15] ERROR - #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - Last Action: Vcs.Checkout.Git
```

Thanks for your help

Dirk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an error when I tried to make a new repository from Android Studio with the token `GIT_REBASE_TOKEN`. After trying everything I rebooted my PC and now the error had `GIT_ASKPASS_TOKEN` error, again nothing changed and the error persisted even after trying everything.

The next day the error token changed back to the original one. But this time I asked a senior to solve the issue which he did (So try out this if it works for you)

---

**SHORT ANSWER**:

Go to the Path where your Android Studio Configuration files are stored, for me they were at `C:\Users\<user>` and delete the folder `.AndroidStudio4.0` (the 4.0 is the version of Android Studio installed, alternatively just change the folder name to anything else). Now when you open your Android Studio again it will ask some default setting questions just like during a fresh install and try to do the clone or do any vcs related thing again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out that I didn't install git before trying to push (Android Studio still allowed me to add git token via settings and commit, error showed up only when pushing).