# Can't add remote for Android Studio - Windows : GIT_ASKPASS_TOKEN environment variable is not defined

Tags: android-studio, gitlab, jgit

I would like to connect my Android Studio project to Gitlab as a school project, but I can't define a new remote using the https: whenever I do it I get this error, and I can't find any issue:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS6td.png)

Is there any known solution?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502059/error-with-git-askpass-token-when-trying-to-clone-git-repository-in-android-stud

Comment: I tried kind of everything in the thread but none of the solutions were working.. I still have the same message

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone the project locally via terminal. It will ask for your username and password. Then you should be able to add remote.

Comment: I didn't clone it through terminal, but I created the remote through terminal, and it indeed asked for my credentials. 
Thanks for the answer!